# NavigationLink broken on watchOS?

Tags: swiftui, watchos, swiftui-navigationlink

All my navigation links suddenly stopped working correctly on my app's companion watch app. I first suspected some issue with my model refreshing causing the NavigationLink to be re-created or such. However, it turned out that even the most simple example is broken.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct cls2_navlinkpushbackApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var view: Int = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            TabView(selection: $view) {
                TestView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Click on the navlink below.")
            NavigationLink(destination: LinkView()) {
                Text("2) Click me!")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(Text("TestView"))
    }
}

struct LinkView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("I will pop back immediately :(")
            .navigationTitle(Text("LinkView"))
    }
}
```

Whenever a NavigationLink is clicked, the destination target is opened and immediately closed. Can anybody confirm this behaviour? I contacted Apple already through a CLS incident but got the advice to create a feedback request instead (which I'm about todo asap, the ID will be placed here then). However, I wonder why nobody else reported the issue so far if this is indeed a bug.

Comment: For what its worth even the [Creating a watchOS App](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-watchos-app) project's navigation seems to be broken (in the simulator).

Comment: This stopped working with the release of WatchOS 8.1
I filed feedback then but have not had any response.

Comment: Hi I saw the same issue, have you figured it out?

Comment: Same problem here. Things work in "real" simulator and on device, but the Landmarks tutorial for WatchOS does not have taps in the List working in the Preview.

Comment: @CodeChimp did you hear back on this? I wonder why there is so little echo on such a substential bug if it's not an edge case..

Comment: @lenny no feedback on this issue received so rather stuck and have abandoned my WatchOS project for now.

Comment: Looks like this is broken in latest Xcode. Might be worth see if it's fixed with the beta