# Landmarks SwiftUI Tutorial - Creating watchOS App - Navigation Broken

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

I'm just doing SwiftUI tutorial and I'm stuck at https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-watchos-app (section 4, Add the Landmarks List).
Everything worked fine till now, navigation links on the watchOS are not working, just nothing happens.
I found on StackOverflow someone with same problem in comments, but there wasn't any reply. ([NavigationLink broken on watchOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70488323/navigationlink-broken-on-watchos#comment124704650_70488323)) Someone said It's broken since watchOS 8.1.
What to do to start the links working? :D

Code:

```swift
ForEach(filteredLandmarks) { landmark in
                    NavigationLink {
                        LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
                    } label: {
                        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                    }
                }.navigationTitle("Landmarks")
```

Project files:
https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/d46bb54c0c90d4e01351338f4627245e/15600/CreatingAwatchOSApp.zip

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @lorem ipsum hey i just updated question with code sample and link for whole project. It's working well on iPhone but not working on wOS.

Comment: Linking the whole project is not what was asked for. Please implement a minimal example that reproduces the problem that you are encountering in the tutorial, and post THAT code. First, it keeps the history on StackOverflow so someone down the road can get the context. Second, you may solve it yourself in working through the code example. That happens a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue in the live preview. Digging around I couldn't find a solution, but when I ran the app in the simulator, the links did work. This was with Xcode 13.4.1.